# Need help creating Hotkeys for WPF controls hosted in a Word application ADDIN

Tags: .net, wpf, vsto, add-in

I created a word application addin which will host couple of WPF controls.

I have to define some hotkeys for wpf buttons. 
So I went ahead and created the same and added them to the inputbindings of respective wpf controls. The hot keys work fine if the focus is on the controls. 
however , if the users are typing into word and then try to press the hotkeys nothing happens and I guess word eats away the commands.

I could probably create a lowlevel keyboard hook and filter it out , but since the app is keyboard intensive I prefer not to use this approach.

Can anyone suggest me any other alternative? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer to this. So I created my custom ribbon in word and added all the required buttons to ribbon to overcome this hurdle.The buttons in window can have shortcut keys.